# Doctrine2 multiple entity managers, no restrictions in between them

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need to use 2 different entity managers, as I need to run $em->clear(); for performance reason - batching of inserts.

My config.yml contains

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                options:
                    1001: true
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
            errorlog:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:
                        type: yml
                        dir: Entity
                        is_bundle: true
                        prefix: AppBundleEntity
                        alias: AppBundleEntity
```

However I'm still getting an error

```
[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]                  
Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle'.
```

From looking at other questions, it seems entities need to be separated into different folders at least. Is this the only solution to use different entity managers in the same bundle?

Comment: Never had much luck with auto_mapping and multiple entity managers.  Try adding mappings to your default and simply use AppBundle: ~ for the value for both

Comment: Thanks Cerad, this works. Please add this as an answer, so I can accept it

Comment: Probably be best if you answered you own question with your new working config.  I no longer use Doctrine and hesitate to paste what I think will work without testing it.  And I am far to lazy to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Cerad s comment, this works:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                options:
                    1001: true

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    AppBundle: ~
            errorlog:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    AppBundle: ~
```